# how to copy an image in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'm using graphics.drawImage to copy an image in Java, but the result is a larger file size, Original image is 220 KB, copied image is 2 MB

How can I reduce the image file size without losing the quality ?

below is the code I used

```
    val graphics = newImage.getGraphics()
    graphics.setColor(Color.white)
    graphics.fillRect(0,0,newImage.getWidth,newImage.getHeight)
    graphics.drawImage(originalImage,imageNewX,imageNewY,null)
    graphics.dispose();
```

Comment: The code you've provided is irrelevant to the problem - "how" the image is encoded is the problem. *"How can I reduce the image file size without losing the quality ?"* - The short answer is, you can't, not really.  Most formats are already compressed (JPEG uses a lossful compression, PNG uses a lossless). One of the primary issues is Java is geared towards speed

Comment: yes, but my problem is I have a JPEG image and I want to copy exactly this image when I do so the copied image size is very large as stated in the question description.

Comment: Do a quick search on ImageIO compression, there are a number of examples - but in increase in compression will reduce the quality. You might need to figure out the original compression/quality - again, I’ve seen examples around showing how it’s done

Comment: You're right, sorry I was setting image type to PNG by mistake.

Comment: If you want to copy a file (containing an image or otherwise), don't use ImageIO, use normal file I/O. See [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) Java tutorial. This will ensure fully lossless copying. No information is added or lost.

Comment: actually I wasn't just copying the image, I was copying and adding padding to it